# How to calculate 3rd root of a number in c++

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to calculate the 3rd root of a number.

For example if 
**n=8->2;
if n=27->3;**

The pow function works well on square root (x^0.5) but it does not work on 3rd root (x^1/3), why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int e = 0.3;
    double k;
    cout << "Enter k:" << endl;
    cin >> k;
    k = pow(k, e);
    cout << "The result of k^1/3 " << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've declared e as an int, and assigned it the value 0.3 (3/10)(which will be cast down to 0) rather than 1/3

Comment: `.3` does not equal `1.0/3`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103769/how-can-i-obtain-the-cube-root-in-c

Comment: This is not a dup.  OP knows to use the `pow` function.  He's just having trouble figuring out how.

Comment: Actually even `pow(k, 1.0 / 3.0)` wouldn't calculate a cube root. Close though.

Comment: @Ben - there is no cast. The value is **converted** to 0.

Comment: Issues of (1/3) aside, why not just use the `cbrt` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding cube root in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269069/finding-cube-root-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

Two issues:

- You declare `e` as an `int` but try to store a `double` value in it, so it gets truncated.  You need to declare `e` as `double` to properly store the value.
- The value you're using for `e` is not correct.  `0.3` is not the same as `1.0/3.0`, so your results will be off.  Use `1.0/3.0` for this value instead.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared the exponent as an integer so it will always be assigned as a zero.  declare it as a double.

inside your main try

```
double e = 1.0/3.0;
double k;
cout << "Enter k:" << endl;
cin >> k;
k = pow(k, e);
cout << "The result of k^1/3 " << k << endl;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use double here:

```
double e = 1./3.;
```

instead of int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double e = 1./3.; // <- this line is changed!
    double k;
    cout << "Enter k:" << endl;
    cin >> k;
    k = pow(k, e);
    cout << "The result of k^1/3 " <<k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```